# NameError: name 'S' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code like below to compute option's implied volatility

```
import scipy.stats
from numpy import sqrt, log, exp, pi

N = scipy.stats.norm.cdf
d1 = (log(S/K) + (r+sigma**2/2)*t) / (sigma*sqrt(t))
d2 = d1 - sigma * sqrt(t)

def bs_price(c_p, S, K, r, t, sigma):
    if c_p == 'c':
        return N(d1) * S - N(d2) * K * exp(-r*t)
    elif c_p == 'p':
        return N(-d2) * K * exp(-r*t) - N(-d1) * S
    else:
        return "Please specify call or put options."

MAX_TRY = 1000
def find_iv_newton(c_p, S, K, r, t, market_price):
    _sigma = 0.5
    for i in range(MAX_TRY):
        _bs_price = bs_price(c_p, S, K, r, t, sigma=_sigma)
        diff = market_price - _bs_price
        vega = S*N_prime(d1)*sqrt(t)
        if abs(diff) < ONE_CENT:
            return _sigma
        _sigma += diff/vega
    return _sigma
```

I am calling it from command prompt like below

```
python -c "from greeks import find_iv_newton; print(find_iv_newton('c', 744.45, 540, 0.02, (13/365), 20))"
```

But I am getting error as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Documents\code\Python\HelloWorld\greeks.py", line 5, in <module>
    d1 = (log(S/K) + (r+sigma**2/2)*t) / (sigma*sqrt(t))
NameError: name 'S' is not defined
```

Please help me in understanding to fix the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: The issue is with this line `d1 = (log(S/K) + (r+sigma**2/2)*t) / (sigma*sqrt(t))`. You should declare `S` first

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try the following code. It should work as expected.

**Code:**

```py
import scipy.stats
from numpy import sqrt, log, exp, pi

def bs_price(c_p, S, K, r, t, sigma, N, d1, d2):
    if c_p == 'c':
        return N(d1) * S - N(d2) * K * exp(-r*t)
    elif c_p == 'p':
        return N(-d2) * K * exp(-r*t) - N(-d1) * S
    else:
        return "Please specify call or put options."

MAX_TRY = 1000
def find_iv_newton(c_p, S, K, r, t, market_price):
    sigma = 0.5
    N = scipy.stats.norm.cdf
    N_prime = scipy.stats.norm.pdf
    d1 = (log(S/K) + (r+sigma**2/2)*t) / (sigma*sqrt(t))
    d2 = d1 - sigma * sqrt(t)
    ONE_CENT = 0.01

    for i in range(MAX_TRY):
        _bs_price = bs_price(c_p, S, K, r, t, sigma, N, d1, d2)
        diff = market_price - _bs_price
        vega = S*N_prime(d1)*sqrt(t)
        if abs(diff) < ONE_CENT:
            return sigma
        sigma += diff/vega
    return sigma


print(find_iv_newton('c', 744.45, 540, 0.02, (13/365), 20))
```

**Output:**

```
-1299695.0147969825
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define `S`, which is not in a function, so it will give an error. Judging by your code, I think it's better to put it in a function.

Answer (score -1):

`S` is not defined in the global scope, where you're trying to use it (Note that `K`, `r`, `t`, and `sigma` are also not defined in the global scope and will cause similar errors).

Try either defining these variables in the global scope or moving any line that uses them into a function where they are defined.